# Spring boot Jpa hibernate Sql Data too long for column 'password' at row 1

Tags: hibernate, maven, jpa, spring-boot

I was able to submit a user registration form just fine last night, but for some reason when I woke up this morning and started working on my web app, the form can no longer submit, I realize something had to have happened but I really can't remember changing anything,  I'm using spring boot, and every time I go to submit my user registration form I get the error `could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement`, and I also get this `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'password' at row 1`.  I have no idea what caused this.  I think it could be something in my user domain object, pom.xml file, or maybe my application.properties.  Here's all three of those, and if anyone could see what's causing the error, and let me know that would be great, thanks in advance. Also if there's any other code that you think could be causing the error, let me know and I'll put it up.

User.java

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,      property = "id")
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

private Long id;

private String username;

private String password;

private String email;

private University university;

private Set<Course> courses = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSets = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<Post> posts = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<Comment> comments = new TreeSet<>();

private Set<Authorities> authorities = new HashSet<>();

public User () {}

public User(User user) {
    this.username = user.getUsername();
    this.password = user.getPassword();
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public CharSequence setPassword(String password) {
    return this.password = password;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@ManyToOne
@NotNull
public University getUniversity() {
    return university;
}

public void setUniversity(University university) {
    this.university = university;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<QuestionAnswerSet> getQuestionAnswerSets() {
    return questionAnswerSets;
}

public void setQuestionAnswerSets(Set<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSets) {
    this.questionAnswerSets = questionAnswerSets;
}
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(Set<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}
public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
public Set<Authorities> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(Set<Authorities> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public static User createUser(String username, String email, String password) {
    User user = new User();

    user.username = username;
    user.email = email;
    user.password = new BCryptPasswordEncoder().encode(password);

    return user;
}

public User(Long id, String username, String password, String email, University university,
        Set<QuestionAnswerSet> questionAnswerSets, Set<Post> posts, Set<Comment> comments, Set<Authorities> authorities) {
    this.id = id;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.university = university;
    this.questionAnswerSets = questionAnswerSets;
    this.posts = posts;
    this.comments = comments;
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public User(UserDetails userDetails) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
}
```

application.properties

```
# DataSource settings: set here your own configurations for the database 
# connection. In this example we have "netgloo_blog" as database name and 
# "root" as username and password.
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizbanks
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = jimmer32

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>QuizbanksBootProject</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-remote-shell</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>

        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: So, what is the length of the password to insert, and how is the password column defined in the database table?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I just define it as a string in the User.java class and then it ends up being 60 characters long due to the password encoder, and the @Entity annotation creates columns for the defined variables in the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but I just did a create drop, and it works.  I guess it was some weird glitch.